# Symfony2 - Add another custom Symfony2 project as a vendor

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, composer-php, vendor

I have two symfony2 projets A and B.
My goal is to add the project B into the project A as a vendor.

What I did:

1. Edited the composer.lock file in the A project to include the project B as vendor:

   ```
   "name": "sciforum/journals_revie_bundle",
       "version": "dev-master",
       "target-dir": "SciForum/JournalsReview",
       "source": {
           "type": "git",
           "url": "ssh://git@dev.mdpi.lab:22/~/projects/journals_review",
           "reference": "dc8ea6a551e5d42b972dd302b75d9ce0a26735f3"
       },
       "require": {
           "php": ">=5.3.3"
       },
       "type": "symfony-bundle",
       "extra": {
           "branch-alias": {
               "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
           }
       },
       "autoload": {
           "psr-0": {
               "SciForum\\JournalsReview\\": ""
           }
       },
       "description": "SciForumJournalsReview",
       "homepage": "http://www.sciforum.net",
       "time": "2014-11-14 11:11:33"
   },
   ```
2. Changed the composer.json in the project B

   ```
   {
   "name" : "sciforum/journals_review_bundle",
   "type" : "symfony-bundle",
   "description" : "SciForumJournalsReviewBundle",
   "homepage" : "http://www.sciforum.net",
   "require" : {
       "php" : ">=5.3.3"
   },
   "  autoload" : {
     "psr-0" : {
           "SciForum\\JournalsReviewBundle\\" : ""
       }
   },
   "target-dir" : "SciForum/JournalsReviewBundle",
   "extra" : {
       "branch-alias" : {
           "dev-master" : "2.0-dev"
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Imported the bundle in the project A AppKernel.php

   ```
   new SciForum\JournalsReview\SciForumJournalsReviewBundle(),
   ```

And when trying to do

```
sudo php composer.phar install
```

I am getting

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package sciforum/journals_review_bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 2
- The requested package sciforum/journals_revie_bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
 see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: It seems there is a typo, "journals_revie_bundle" instead of "journals_review_bundle"...

Comment: Sorry, the typo is in the question, in the code it is ok, I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using custom vendors, what I did is that I included this custom bundle as a secondary bundle in my main project, and everything works perfectly well.